# change td background color based on the option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the td background color based on the color value selected in dropdown.

**HTML :**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Channel</th>
<th>Health</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
  <select >
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Amber</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.tdcolor').change( function() {
     $(this).css('background-color','green');
 });
});
```

The above jquery is not highlighting the background color of `td` element holding `tdcolor` class.

If someone could help me how to change this using jquery, it would be great.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pseudo-class` selector in order to get the `selected` text from your dropdown.

```
var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.tdcolor').change( function() {
     $(this).css('background-color',$(this).find(':selected').text());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Channel</th>
<th>Health</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
  <select >
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Blue</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yours is changing the adjacent `td` element. I just need to change the `td` block having the dropdown. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color').change(function() {//add an id to html and use as selector
    $(this).parent("td").css('background-color', $('option:selected', this).text());//use the text of selected option as parameter
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Channel</th>
    <th>Health</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select id='color'>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Amber</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').change( function() {
     $(".tdcolor").css('background-color','green');
 });
});
```

Should be .tdcolor not ddcolor

The event should be on `select`